# Missing Perl dependencies not actually missing

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, otrs

I'm trying to install OTRS Help Desk on an EC2 instance of Amazon Web Services. I'm following the installation instructions [here](http://otrs.github.io/doc/manual/admin/stable/en/html/installation.html#rhel-installing-rpm). But when I try to install otrs, I get the following errors:

```
Error: Package: otrs-4.0.8-02.noarch (/otrs-4.0.8-02.noarch)
       Requires: perl(Archive::Zip)
Error: Package: otrs-4.0.8-02.noarch (/otrs-4.0.8-02.noarch)
       Requires: perl(Template)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

When I try to install Archive::Zip using cpan:

```
cpan[2]> install Archive::Zip
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Sat, 06 Jun 2015 19:41:02 GMT
Archive::Zip is up to date (1.46).
```

Any idea why it can't find the dependency?

Comment: Because OTRS is an rpm package and it looks for the perl modules to be installed as rpm's as well. yum doesn't know about cpan.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there any way I can get the rpm database to recognize that the modules are installed?

Comment: rpm doesn't know anything about Perl modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments above point out, OTRS is an rpm package that looks for other rpm's. There's no coordination between that and CPAN. So the solution is to find the .rpm file using something like [rpmfind.net](http://www.rpmfind.net). In my case, then I would use `wget` to download the rpm, and then I was able to install the dependencies.

Comment: Please do not just go out to rpmfind.net to find RPMs for your Linux deployment. Just use your system's package manager. `perl-Archive-Zip` is in base. Just use `yum install -y "perl(Archive::Zip)" to install it. If you'd `yum install` OTRS as well, this is supposed to install the dependencies automatically.

Comment: I tried `yum install -y "perl(Archive::Zip)" and kept getting a message that no such package existed. That's why I had to go looking for the rpm. The errors I cite above came as a result of running `yum install -y otrs-*.rpm`. For whatever reason, maybe because of something with AWS, it couldn't resolve the dependencies on its own.

Comment: Yeah, you'll not have the correct yum repos set I guess. Did you try `yum clean all && yum search perl-Archive-Zip` ?

Comment: @MichielB. Nope. I'll have to try that next time.