# Probe::Perl package installed but is not being recognized

Tags: perl, perl-module, yum

I have installed the Perl Module Probe-Perl-0.k03 as the Sys Admin gave me a very stripped down version of Perl.  I have installed it along with the others, but when I go to run the yum install(yum install perl-CPAN*) it is still stating that they are not installed.  It appears to be pointing to the right location of my perl which is /usr/bin/perl.  Any guidance possibly?

**Dependencies resolution errors given by yum install:**

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: perl-CPAN-Reporter-1.2011-2.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: perl(Probe::Perl)
Error: Package: perl-CPAN-Reporter-1.2011-2.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: perl(Capture::Tiny)
Error: Package: perl-CPAN-Reporter-1.2011-2.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: perl(File::HomeDir) >= 0.58
Error: Package: perl-CPAN-Reporter-1.2011-2.el7.noarch (epel)
       Requires: perl(Config::Tiny) >= 2.08
```

**Perl package installed:**

Probe-Perl-0.k03

**Install steps:**

```
[root@sandbox-prod Probe-Perl-0.03]# pwd
/root/Probe-Perl-0.03
[root@sandbox-prod Probe-Perl-0.03]# perl Makefile.PL
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Probe::Perl
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
[root@sandbox-prod Probe-Perl-0.03]# make
Skip blib/lib/Probe/Perl.pm (unchanged)
Manifying 1 pod document
[root@sandbox-prod Probe-Perl-0.03]# make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/author-critic.t .. skipped: these tests are for testing by the author
t/basic.t .......... ok
All tests successful.
Files=2, Tests=19,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.04 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.07 CPU)
Result: PASS
[root@sandbox-prod Probe-Perl-0.03]# make install
Manifying 1 pod document
Appending installation info to /usr/lib64/perl5/perllocal.pod
```

Comment: yum only knows about rpm's, but you didn't install Probe::Perl via an rpm. See [Missing Perl dependencies not actually missing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30687167/176646)

Comment: Hmm.  I installed the other packages like MM_Unix.pm the same way.  Okay thanks I tried the install on my end and got back: No package perl

[root@sandbox-prod Probe-Perl-0.03]# yum install -y "perl(Probe::Perl)"
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
No package perl(Probe::Perl) available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Package names of Perl modules on RPM-based systems generally follow the same pattern; the package name for module `Foo::Bar` is `perl-Foo-Bar`. You want `yum install perl-Probe-Perl`.

Comment: thanks.  It is still saying package not available:
rhel-rs-for-rhel-7-server-eus-rpms                                                                                                                                                      | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
No package perl-Probe-Perl available

Comment: It must be under a different name.  can I search for that on the rpmfind.net site?

Comment: Ok I found the package.  ftp://195.220.108.108/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/x86_64/os/Packages/p/perl-Probe-Perl-0.03-5.fc23.noarch.rpm

Comment: Thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot did a yum install on that perl probe package and I have another module to install named :Error: Package: perl-Probe-Perl-0.03-5.fc23.noarch (/perl-Probe-Perl-0.03-5.fc23.noarch)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.22.0)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem

Comment: Please let me know how I can give you credit for this answer.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot just post it as an anser so OP can tick it :)

Comment: @simbabque I'm still trying to decide if I should VtC as a dupe of the question I linked in my first comment.

Comment: @This I started deciding ;)